# How to use multiple editor with only one toolbar in reactjs (google docs clone)

Tags: reactjs, editor, google-docs, jodit

I'm trying to make google docs clone where I'm trying multiple editor on one page (vertically aligned like google docs ), and I want a single toolbar to make the control over all editor containers, so it can determine which editor to edit when mouse move into the specific editor. I am using jodit-react package.

Is there any workaround to make it possible to have one toolbar control multiple Editors?
Is there any other editor where I can make multiple pages like google docs?

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import React, { useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "jodit";
import "jodit/build/jodit.min.css";
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const Editor = () => {
  const editor1 = useRef(null);
  const editor2 = useRef(null);
  const editor3 = useRef(null);
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([
    { id: 1, content: "" },
    { id: 2, content: "" },
    { id: 3, content: "" },
  ]);

  const config1 = useMemo(
    () => ({
      height: 500,
      toolbar: true,
      toolbarSticky: true,
    }),
    []
  );
  const config2 = useMemo(
    () => ({
      height: 500,
      toolbar: true,
      toolbarSticky: true,
    }),
    []
  );

  const config3 = useMemo(
    () => ({
      height: 500,
      toolbar: false,
    }),
    []
  );

  const handleContentChange = (content, activePage) => {
    const updatedPages = pages.map((page) => {
      if (page.id === activePage) {
        return { ...page, content };
      }
      return page;
    });
    setPages(updatedPages);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {pages?.map((page) => (
        <div
          key={page.id}
          style={{ border: "2px solid red", margin: "20px 250px" }}
        >
          <JoditEditor
            ref={page.id === 1 ? editor1 : page.id === 2 ? editor2 : editor3}
            value={page.content}
            config={page.id === 1 ? config1 : page.id === 2 ? config2 : config3}
            tabIndex={1}
            className=""
            onChange={(newContent) => handleContentChange(newContent, page.id)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```